# Objective-C for each item in NSArray create UI Label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this block of code here:

```
for (id object in _theParamenterArray) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = @"Custom Label";
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a label for each item in `NSArray`. My array has 3 rows and each row as the following values: `Assemble`, `Division`, `Project` and `WorkOrder` and I want to put each value in a `UILabel`. how would I accomplish this?

I have tried the following:

```
    int counter = 0;
for (id object in _theParamenterArray) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Assemble"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Division"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:labelTwo];

    UILabel *labelThree = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Project"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:labelThree];

    UILabel *labelFour = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"WorkOrder"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:labelFour];
    counter++;
}
```

but it only displays the WorkOrder for all three rows, I am trying to get all values from each row.

Here is a screenshot of my array:

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you supplied, could you please detail your problem further?

Comment: My issue is when I run this code, I only get 1 label that says Custom Label

Comment: you are setting all the lables at same frame, please change the frame of each lable.

Comment: What kind of object is `object`?  You call it `id` but if you're going to get values out of it, that's easier with a known object type.

Comment: Any reason why you don't go for a `UITableView`? To me it sounds like the perfect use case for a table view.

Comment: All the four lables still placed at same frame, as you are increwmenting the counter after all the labels are framed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is when I run this code, I only get 1 label that says "Custom Label"

You do get four labels that look like one because they sit on top of each other, and all say the same thing (i.e. "Custom Label").

In order to fix this, you need to do two things:

- **Make sure that you give your labels different frames** - make a counter, decide how far apart the labels should be, and adjust coordinates accordingly, and
- **Set different text into the labels** - for example, use `label.text = object` (assuming that `object` is `NSString`)

The way you adjust the origin of the frame depends on where you want your labels to be in relation to each other. To stack them vertically, use this code:

```
int counter = 0;
for (id object in _theParamenterArray) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Assemble"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Division"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:labelTwo];

    UILabel *labelThree = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Project"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:labelThree];

    UILabel *labelFour = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
    label.text = [object objectForKey:@"WorkOrder"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:labelFour];
    counter++;
}
```

The `10+30*counter` expression places your labels at positions

```
(10, 10)   (110, 10)  (210, 10)  (310, 10)
(10, 40)   (110, 40)  (210, 40)  (310, 40)
(10, 70)   (110, 70)  (210, 70)  (310, 70)
(10, 100) (110, 100) (210, 100) (310, 100)
```

Comment: (10,10) or (10,20 ) ?

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks! It was a copy-paste error from OP's code, which was a copy-paste from the prior version of my code :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight still having issues....all that displays is the WorkOrder for each item

Comment: @user979331 Did you see the changes that I made to the code after your edit? I mean, the 10, 110, 210, and 310 part?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes I did...I have attached a screenshot of what my array looks like

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the Y value like below (Or set the CGRect to be where you want the labels)

```
NSArray *obj = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
int x = 200;
for (NSString *object in obj) {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, x, 200, 20)];
    x+= 40;
    label.text = object;
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: You are creating labels that growh in height but start at the same coordinates. They will overlap. 

Try `CGRectMake(10, x, 200, 35)` instead. :-)